# how can I kill Insects that are boring holes in concrete

Tags: repair, concrete

I have insects that are boring holes in my driveway and garage floor.  Are there any remedies that would kill Them?

Comment: How do you know it's insects doing this?  I'm not aware of any insect that is capable of boring through concrete although rats have been known to do so.  I suggest contacting a professional exterminator.

Comment: Probably those little guy from "The Day the Earth Stood Still".  :-)

Comment: What is the size of these holes?

Comment: There are mud dauber wasps that create little pockets of "dirt" containing their larvae in crevices or existing holes, but they do not drill.

Comment: I would like to see a photo of these impressive insects or at least of the holes they make.